# Change limit size of mouse cursor in window 7

Tags: windows, cursor, mouse

In windows 7 OS normal screen.

I have try to change mouse cursor to image with size **larger than 32x32 pixel**.

EX: 300x300 pixel because I want to capture video on screen when I moving **picture of large circle (size 300x300 pixel )** on screen.

I had try to change mouse cursor size in control panel mouse menu and ease access menu but not found way to break limit size of cursor.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the video recording software would be the place to tackle this, instead of the OS.